# Can you add a label to an array.forEach in Google Script?

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, anonymous-function

I want to loop through all elements in an array using `array.forEach(` and break or continue the iterations based upon the element's value. However, the Google Scripts compiler says that I need to have a label on each `break` or `continue`. Can this be done in the following gist?

```
for( i in traces ){
  environment = null;
  traces[i].servers.forEach( function(server){
    if( server.environment=="DEVELOPMENT" )
      environment = "DEVELOPMENT";
      break;  // got the earliest environment so no reason to keep on looking
    }
    if( server.environment=="QA" )
      environment = "QA";
      continue; // might get DEVELOPMENT next time
    }
    if( server.environment=="PRODUCTION" )
      environment = "PRODUCTION";
      continue; // might get DEVELOPMENT or QA next time
    }        
  });
  . . .
}
```

Alternatively, how could I do this whole thing better?

Comment: According to MDN 'There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong tool.' [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, how about this workaround? In this workaround, it uses `some()` instead of `forEach()`. There are no method for stopping the loop at `forEach()` as [@Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7215091/cooper) mentioned. In the case of `some()`, there is a method for stopping the loop.

#### Modification points:

- When `some()` is used for this situation, the loop can be stopped by returning `true`.

  - When the string values for searching are not found, `res` returns `false`.
  - When one of the string values for searching is found, `res` returns `true`.

#### Modified script:

```
for( i in traces) {
  environment = null;
  var res = traces[i].servers.some(function(server) {
    switch (server.environment) {
      case "DEVELOPMENT":
        environment = "DEVELOPMENT";
        return true;
      case "QA":
        environment = "QA";
        break;
      case "PRODUCTION":
        environment = "PRODUCTION";
        break;
    }
  });

// do something

}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, when `DEVELOPMENT` is found, the loop is stopped and `res` is `true`.
- Even when `QA` and `PRODUCTION` are found, the loop is not stopped and the loop is continued. For example, if `DEVELOPMENT` is not found while `QA` is found, `environment` and `res` are `QA` and `false`, respectively.

  - From your script, I thought that you might need such flow.
- I used `switch` instead of `if` for this modification, because it is a bit faster than `if`. The result which measured this is [here](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/cef47530a58f2d8692cdb1a9d257907b). From your question, I thought that you might need the script with the low cost. So I used `switch`.

#### Reference:

- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

If I misunderstand what you want, I'm sorry.